# Configure WAN in my netgear dgn1000v3

Tags: router, wan

I have [this router](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/DGN1000v3.aspx). I am using it as a modem i.e input is given via a RJ-11 jack. Now I am switching to an ISP that is giving me co-axial cable (RJ-45) as input. I think my router supports WAN.

But there is no option in the netgear firmware to change one of the four RJ45 ports to input port so I can plug in the input cable.

How can I use my router's WAN option? Should I install a new firmware on my router to enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the RJ45 coming from your cable modem into the "internet" port on your router...

https://kb.netgear.com/22697/How-to-configure-your-NETGEAR-router-for-cable-internet-connection-with-NETGEAR-genie